# Why plt.imshow() isn't working in matplotlib

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I'm trying to run a simple code that takes a traffic lights image & displays it as grayscale --> 'Original' and then takes the same image and displays only the parts of it which correspond to the upper and lower thresholds I pre-defined --> 'bright'. However, the following code when I run it, displays nothing.
when I change plt.imshow() to cv2.imshow() it does, so I'm confused as to why this happens. Both libraries are installed correctly. I even tried adding plt.show() at the end of the code, but still no output.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


original = cv2.imread('traffic_lights.jpeg')
plt.imshow(original,cmap='gray')
lower=150
upper = 254
bright = cv2.inRange(original,lower,upper)
plt.imshow(bright,cmap='gray')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify a figure and axes, then plot the image on the axes.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


original = cv2.imread('traffic_lights.jpeg')
plt.imshow(original,cmap='gray')
lower = 150
upper = 254
bright = cv2.inRange(original,lower,upper)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(bright,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It helps to first convert your image as opencv image into the right color scale with cv2.COLOR_xxx:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

original = cv2.imread('traffic_light.jpg')
original = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
lower, upper = 150, 254
bright = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
plt.imshow(bright,cmap='gray')
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV `imread` functions reads the image in a `B`, `G`, `R` fashion.

- Therefore if you read the image with `imread` and want to display with `pyplot`, first you need to convert the image into the `R`, `G`, `B` then display.
- For instance:

---

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = cv2.imread("lights.jpg")
    img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
```

Result:

---

[image]

- If you don't convert using `cvtColor` the result will be:

---

[image]

- The above for the `RGB` images, for gray images the correct answer will be:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = cv2.imread("lights.jpg")
    img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    plt.imshow(img_rgb, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
    lower = 150
    upper = 254
    bright = cv2.inRange(img_rgb, lower, upper)
    plt.imshow(bright, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
```

Result:

---

[image] [image]